# How to improve performance of checking a condition for each row in a 10M row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I am working on Python flask web services and the app will be receiving one file either in csv or xlsx. I read this file and convert it to a Pandas dataframe.

Now I need to iterate through each row of dataframe and check a specific condition. If a condition is met then I need to update a few columns in the same dataframe.

I have done it using below code but I am not happy with the performance.

```
def ExecuteInParallel(convertContract,ratesDf,inputDf):
    for index, row in inputDf.iterrows():
        currencyFound = ratesDf.query(
            'CCY1 =="{0}" and CCY2 == "{1}"'
            .format(
                row[convertContract.INPUT_CURRENCY],
                row[convertContract.RETURN_CURRENCY]
            )
        )
        if len(currencyFound.index) == 0:
            raise BadRequest(
                "Given Currency combination not found with provided date.")

        currentrate = currencyFound.Rate.values[0]
        if convertContract.ROUNDING != None and convertContract.ROUNDING != "":
            rounding = int(convertContract.ROUNDING)
            if rounding > 0:
                convertedamount = round(
                    float(row[convertContract.INPUT_AMOUNT]) * currentrate,
                    int(convertContract.ROUNDING)
                )
                inputDf.at[index,convertContract.RETURN_VALUE] = convertedamount
        else:
            convertedamount = float(row[convertContract.INPUT_AMOUNT]) * currentrate
            inputDf.at[index,convertContract.RETURN_VALUE] = convertedamount
        if convertContract.RETURN_RATE == "True":
            inputDf.at[index,convertContract.RETURN_VALUE + "_FX Rate"] = currentrate
```

I have done some performance analysis and concluded it is taking about 470 seconds to iterate through 10k rows.

I want to perform it for 10M rows. So I tried thread programming in Python save above funtion call but with smaller dataframes. I created chunks of 500 rows dataframe and pass to above method its own chunk but there is not even a single second difference noticed.

How can I improve this?

```
def ConvertdataFramesValues(self,contract,ratesDf,inputDf):
    try:
        treadList = []
        size = 500
        list_of_dfs = list(inputDf.loc[i:i + size - 1,:] for i in range(0, len(inputDf),size))
        for frame in list_of_dfs:
           
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=ExecuteInParallel,args=(convertContract,ratesDf,frame))
            treadList.append(t1)
            t1.start()

        for t in treadList:
            t.join()

        inputDf = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
        print(list_of_dfs[0].head())
        return inputDf

    except Exception as e:
        msg = "unable to convert data frame values. " + str(e)
        print(msg)
        raise BadRequest(msg)
```

Comment: Do not iterate the data. Try to list your logic out first.

Comment: As noted above - try expressing you logic in terms of column operations, where columns are variables you deal with. A kind rules of thumb is magnitude of a min per million rows is ok for complex query, several min per 10k rows is too complex algorithm (of course machine-dependent). For real help you need to provide a minimum working example of what you are up to, otherwise it is vrry hard to understsnd what goes on in your algorithm.

Comment: This is the actual logic ExecuteInParallel method is iterating df row by row. I have pasted my entire logic. If you provide it any two data frame, one for reference data and second one for data to iterate, it will work without any issue. The only problem I am facing is performance